# Redirect to Asp.Net MVC error page while client logged in through Wi-Fi Connected Laptop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, wifi

I have two sites. One is 80 Port and another is 8080 Port. The First One is perfectly logged in through LAN and Wi-Fi network from everywhere. Even if I change port for that no error occurred.

But another one is perfectly logged in through both LAN and Wi-Fi from different laptop of my home or office. Even Client office can work perfectly with LAN connection. But when client wants to login the site with Wi-Fi network from their different branch office, The Login page is redirected to Asp.Net MVC default error page.

I can't understand whether it is networking problem or login authentication problem or connection string problem. Please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for your nice co-operation.

Comment: Compare iis settings and folder security settings for two sites. it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is solved. I don't know why some WiFi Network can't detect **IPAddress.Parse(Request.UserHostName)** while the site is on Live.
After commented the following lines everything is now Ok on both LAN and Wifi.
But the awful matter is that now I have to avoid to show Login PC name from the login info list.

```
   private void  GetLoggedPCInfo()
    {
        //string ip = Request.UserHostName;
        //IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        //IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);
        //List<string> compName = GetIPHost.HostName.ToString().Split('.').ToList();
        //Session["LoginPC_Name"] = compName.First().ToUpper();
        string dateTime =  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
        Session["LoginDateTime"] = dateTime.ToString();
    }
```